# How C manages the memory

Tags: arrays, c

The answer should be 1 and 1. But why the result is 1 and 2. Arr is not a global variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add (int arr[1])
{
    arr[0] = arr[0]+1;
}

int main() {
    int arr[1]={1};
    printf("%d\n",arr[0]);
    add(arr);

    printf("%d", arr[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing the `add` function a pointer to the first element of the array. Why would that *not* cause your 'original' data to be changed?

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers to first element when passed as function argument.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with memory management, C++, C++17 or function pointers. Please don't add completely irrelevant tags to the post.

Answer (score 2):

> The answer should be 1 and 1

No, it should be 1 and 2.

`void add (int arr[1])` creates a local parameter variable named `arr`, to which you pass the variable also named `arr` in the caller.

There are two rules in C informally called "array decay", which means that whenever an array is used in an expression or function parameter declaration, it gets adjusted implicitly by the compiler into a pointer to the first element of the array.

So `add(arr);` is 100% equivalent to `add(&arr[0]);`.

And the function defintion `void add (int arr[1])` is equivalent to `void add (int* arr)`. This always happens, you can't pass arrays by value in C even though `void add (int arr[1])` looks like it does that.

For this reason, the `arr` in your function points at the `arr` in the caller. And when you update the contents pointed at, you update the contents of the variable in main.

Answer (score 0):

When an array is declared as a function argument, it becomes a pointer. That's just the way it is. Here is a snippet with corresponding errors ans warnings that proves it:

```
$ cat main.c 
void foo(int arg[10]) {
    int arr[10];
    float *x;

    arg = x;
    arr = x;
}

$ gcc -c main.c 
main.c: In function ‘foo’:
main.c:5:9: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘float *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    5 |     arg = x;
      |         ^
main.c:6:9: error: assignment to expression with array type
    6 |     arr = x;
      |         ^
```

So in this case, `arr` is an array, but `arg` is not. This means that your `add` function is equivalent to this:

```
void add (int *arr)
{
    arr[0] = arr[0]+1;
}
```

And when you pass an array to a function, it will automatically decay to a pointer. So the output 1 and 2 is the expected output.